# import R model into Python

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, random-forest

I'm working on classification project aiming to predict the presence/absence of locust in a specified region. The machine learnig method i'm using is Random Forest. The learning phase was already done in R as a result I have the model written in R and I need to use it in an app developped using Python.
I wonder to know if there is a way t do this because I don't have much time to rewrite the model in Python.

Comment: Try to serialize it in R and load it in python.

Comment: would you explain how or maybe mention a link where to find some informations.

Comment: Which implementation of RF are you using in R?

Comment: I didn't implement it myself, it's a classification.

Comment: Yes.... What I meant to say was which library of R are you using?.. Check this out: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/197335/is-it-possible-to-share-models-between-r-scikit-learn-and-spark

Comment: they used 'randomForest' library

Comment: the link you've metionned is for exporting models to be used in Spark not in Python